# Need correct syntax for a system of simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations, but I'm new to mathematica and don't know how to enter into the notebook cell the correct format.

```
J^2 + L^2 + B^2 = K^2 + M^2 + D^2
J*K + L*M + B*D = sqr (K^2 + M^2 + D^2)*sqr (J^2 + L^2 + B^2)*.5
```

B and D are the unknowns, everything else are constants.

Comment: `Solve[{J^2 + L^2 + B^2 == K^2 + M^2 + d^2, J*K + L*M + B*d == Sqrt[K^2 + M^2 + d^2] Sqrt[J^2 + L^2 + B^2]*1/2}, {B, d}]` Watch out for case sensitive function names, for capitalized symbols conflicting with system defined symbols and functions, for `=` versus `==` versus `===`, for `()` versus `[]` versus `{}`. You might try `Simplify[Solve[yourstuff]]` to make your result smaller and easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are telling Mathematica that two equations are equal, you need to use 
the Equal operator: `==`. The single equal sign `=` is the Set (or assignment) operator. Therefore you can also have things like this:

```
a = LHS == RHS
```

To solve two simultaneous equations, the general syntax is `Solve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {var1, var2}]`. Functions such as `Sqrt` or `Sin` must be capitalized. You also have to use square brackets and not any other brackets to encase things inside them. For example: `Sqrt[a - b]` and not `Sqrt(a - b)`. Here's your desired equation (note that you need curly brackets to encase the equations in the first argument):

```
Solve[{J^2 + L^2 + B^2 == K^2 + M^2 + D^2, J*K + L*M + B*D == Sqrt[K^2 + M^2 + D^2] * Sqrt[J^2 + L^2 + B^2]*.5}, {B, D}]
```

An alternate way to write it would be to just use `&&` instead of a comma separated list in the first argument:

```
Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, {var1, var2}]
```

The output in your case would look like `{{B -> some eqn}, {D -> some eqn}}`.

If you would like to read more, here's a link to the documentation which contains examples on using the `Solve` function: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html